# Extension of research on optimisation to a relatively complex level

Tags: optimization, heuristics

I'm doing research for academic credential on the use of metaheuristic optimisation of building envelopes/enclosures, focusing on the aspect of its thermal performance.

The subject was handled with heavy emphasis on the integration of algorithm into the architectural design process by evaluating building thermal performance through energy simulation and feeding back the results into the algorithm.

**My Question is:** having somewhat limited knowledge of mathematical optimisation, and very limited knowledge of programming languages; how would you advise me to extend my research? i.e. What references should I start looking into? Which computational programmes/software would best serve my purpose? (all within the general direction of my research topic mentioned above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will typically get the most significant steps forward if you can concisely state a problem in terms of mathematics. When you have a concise formulation in terms of

- what the free variables are
- what the objective function is
- what the constraints are

then the next step is to find algorithms that are well-suited to the problem at hand (e.g., can you show that the problem is convex? equality/inequality-constrained? continuous or integer?). The book I always recommend to learn about optimization methods is the one by Nocedal and Wright, "Numerical Optimization". You don't need to understand everything in it, but it's an easy read and it will give you an idea of how to classify algorithms and how to approach problems.